# How to reload a ViolentMonkey user script during development?

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

Is there a way to reload a script without having to refresh the page? As in during dev, after you save an update in the dashboard, how can you just refresh script to see updated logic?

Comment: Why is not having to refresh the page a requirement?

Comment: @DoomTay Just makes it easier and faster to develop if I can take current state of site and just apply newer logic to it. I'm doing so without this, but it's just annoying to have to refresh page each time i make a tweak.

Comment: No this is all but impossible and a poor idea; see the linked Q&A (and others).  If you *carefully* do as much development in the console as possible, you can get much done without needing to reload the page.